# when using php file unlink it does not delete the file

Tags: php, unlink

this code has worked in the past, nothing has changed that I know of?

very basic code:

```
<?PHP
$file_name = $_GET['sn'].'.zip';
if (file_exists($file_name)) {
    unlink($file_name);
} else {
    // File not found.
}
?>
```

and to access the delete.php file im simply running

www.url.com/delete.php?sn=file.zip
"file.zip is replaced by the actual filename"

it runs fine, no errors, and yes the file is there.

any thoughts on why this is no longer deleting the file?

Comment: It doesn't show any errors, probably because of `file_exists($file_name)`. Add `echo realpath($file_name);` to the "else" branch to see what file it tried to delete.

Comment: Added - did not help but i figured out what I was doing wrong.. not sure how to mark this as solved

Comment: Delete the question. It's not even complete and thus off-topic. Please, as a new user, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I feel Really stupid but the answer was right in front of me

i dont type www.url.com/delete.php?sn=file.zip

I type www.url.com/delete.php?sn=file

the .zip is added from the code... Sorry for wasting anyone's time